# Matlab - setting up the scale in imagesc automatically

Tags: image, matlab

I am trying to compare plots that I create by matlab imagesc, and hence need the color limits to be identical to the higher one.

I tried digging, but couldn't find an easy way to do that, or at least figure out the limits without opening the colormap editor.

Thanks much for any help!

Alon.

Comment: Please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the limits of the color-scale using `caxis`

```
img1 = randn(100);
img2 = rand(100);

%# find global min/max
clim(1) = min(min(img1(:)),min(img2(:)));
clim(2) = max(max(img1(:)),max(img2(:)));

figure
ah1 = axes;
imagesc(img1)
caxis(ah1,clim)

%# show the other figure set the same limits to colormap
figure
ah2 = axes
imagesc(img2);
caxis(ah2,clim)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imagesc(name_of_your_matrix,[0 255]);
```

This display your image and scale it with the [0 255] intensity scale. Of course you can increase it for displaying your image with more colors.

hope this was helpful.